# Why can't I convert a number to a sting on a type number|string, TS2322

Tags: typescript

The incoming JSON sometimes have a number instead of a string, so I want to accept both, but always convert it to a string.

A simplified version of the code:

```js
const j: string = "1";
let v: number|string = JSON.parse(j);
if(typeof v === "number") {
    v += '';
}
console.log('v: ', v);
```

That code gives the error:

```
ts2322test.ts:4:2 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

4  v += '';
   ~
```

The variable v is of the type number|string, so it should accept the string.
and if I skip the if-statement it accept the code:

```js
const j: string = "1";
let v: number|string = JSON.parse(j);
v += '';
console.log('v: ', v);
```

Can I somehow remind TypeScript that v accepts both numbers and strings?

Comment: `v = v + ''` works

Comment: `const v : string = JSON.parse(j).toString()`

Comment: So the "type guard" triggers on `v += ''` but not for `v = v + ''`, thats feels odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert number to string with String() function

```
const j: string = "1";
let v: number|string = JSON.parse(j);
if(typeof v === "number") {
    v = String(v);
}
console.log('v: ', v);
```

Comment: Seams like just changing `v += '';` to `v = v + '';` get rid of the TS2322 warning.